# Images are not aligned well (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a simple image gallery.
I have this code:

```
    <div class="{{ $image->category }}">
  <img
      src="{{ $image->path }}"
      alt="{{ $image->image_name }}"
      class="{{ $image->id }} img-thumbnail col-md-4"
      data-id="{{ $image->id }}"
      width="304" height="236"
      >
  </div>
```

(ignore the `{{ }}` - It's for laravel usage).

This is the output I get - misaligned images in some sections of the gallery:
http://2.1m.yt/zy-iyJO.png
http://2.1m.yt/KxfgdD.png

how can I make it all align well? should I manually resize the images I have? or can I write some code to automatically resize the images? I see using `width="304" height="236"`
 does not help in this case.

Would appreciate you help, thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't abstract the img class to something standard, and attach your width and height values to that class?

Comment: @Chris thanks for replying.
Could you give me an example, so I could better understand your suggestion? thanks.

Comment: Your code includes the following:

      class="{{ $image->id }} img-thumbnail col-md-4"

Is this essential for laravel to correctly function? (I don't know anything about laravel).

If not, you can replace that with the following:

      class="imageTemplate"

Then you place the following in your style sheet (or you can build a style sheet and include it).

      img.imageTemplate {
      width: 304; 
      height: 236;}

Comment: okay I get you now @Chris . The thing's that these 2 properties ```img-thumbnail col-md-4``` are used for showing images as thumbnails and 3 images in a row, and also making them responsive with bootstrap. (those 2 are bootstrap properties).

Comment: Ok. Have you tried replacing your height and width with a style tag? Something along the lines of the following:   style="height:236; width:304;"

Comment: just did it like you have suggested (hope it's the right way):
```<div class="{{ $image->category }}">
      <img
          src="{{ $image->path }}"
          alt="{{ $image->image_name }}"
          class="{{ $image->id }} img-thumbnail col-md-4"
          data-id="{{ $image->id }}"
          style="height:236; width:304;"
          >
      </div>```
Still getting the exact view with the misalignments.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117466/discussion-between-osherdo-and-chris).